# Pandas: DataFrame Difference Function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve the following problem using Pandas:

DataFrame 1:

```
Apple  Banana Orange
Orange Banana Apple
Kiwi   Lime   Apple
Banana Apple  Orange
```

DataFrame 2:

```
Orange Banana Apple
Apple  Banana Orange
Apple  Orange Apple
Kiwi   Apple  Apple
```

Function:

```
DataFrame 1 - DataFrame 2
```

Output:

```
Kiwi   Lime  Apple
Banana Apple  Orange
```

In essence, I'm dealing with categorical variables in multiple columns, and would like to find rows that are in DataFrame 1, but not in DataFrame 2. I would also like to keep the rows in order, as demonstrated in the output. i.e not this:

```
Banana Apple  Orange
Kiwi   Lime  Apple
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a [pandas.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) and then drop any resulting joins.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Categ1':['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Banana'],
                    'Categ2':['Banana', 'Banana', 'Lime', 'Apple'],
                    'Categ3':['Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Categ1':['Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Kiwi'],
                    'Categ2':['Banana', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
                    'Categ3':['Apple', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple']})

# MERGE BOTH DATA FRAMES   
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Categ1', 'Categ2', 'Categ3'])

# DROP FROM ORIGINAL DF1 ANY ITEMS IN MERGED
df1 = df1.drop(merged.index)
```

Data Frame Outputs:

```
ORIGINAL DF1
   Categ1  Categ2  Categ3
0   Apple  Banana  Orange
1  Orange  Banana   Apple
2    Kiwi    Lime   Apple
3  Banana   Apple  Orange

MERGED DF
   Categ1  Categ2  Categ3
0   Apple  Banana  Orange
1  Orange  Banana   Apple

FINAL DF1
   Categ1 Categ2  Categ3
2    Kiwi   Lime   Apple
3  Banana  Apple  Orange
```